# I can't get int id from self

Tags: odoo, onchange, self, odoo-13

I have a problem with get id from self.

I create the TransientModel which open a new window with selected records and in this i have my email composer.

And when i select email template i have this method:

```
@api.onchange('email_template_id')
def _onchange_template_id(self):
    if self.email_template_id:
        print('self1', self)
        print('self2', self._origin)
        print('self3', self._origin.id)
        print('self4', self.id)
        print('currency_id', self.currency_id)
        values = self.env['mail.compose.message'].generate_email_for_composer(self.email_template_id.id, [self._origin.id])[self._origin.id]
        self.email_body = values['body']
```

and i wanna to use composer to create body from my template.
But with this NewId i can't use generate_email_for_composer.

Debug for my prints:

```
self1 purchase.order.groupmail.wizard(<NewId 0x7f905ff24e90>,)
self2 purchase.order.groupmail.wizard()
self3 False
self4 <NewId 0x7f905ff24e90>
currency_id res.currency(17,)
```

Comment: your object is not saved yet ?

Comment: you may want to do it in create() or write() functions

Comment: @Paxmees Yes my object is not save becouse i have open new form.
Fields in this form are filled by methods which use data from context. And there i wanna use onchange to get body with use data from my nonsaved form.

Comment: It seems to be wizard, maybe you want some other object's id

Comment: Try to create the `purchase.order.groupmail.wizard` the record before you open the form view (you have to specify the `res_id` when opening the form view).

Comment: @Kenly i try to do this without save but it impossible.
Olny one solution i find with add button for _onchange_template_id and it update but don't reload active form. So i go another way and save record. There is the solution with with js: https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-to-refresh-the-main-window-from-wizard-through-button-action-35753
But i dont know how to use this.

Comment: If you need to reload the view use the OCA module [web_ir_actions_act_view_reload](https://github.com/OCA/web/tree/13.0/web_ir_actions_act_view_reload)